# Roles claim not present in token error when using graph API to connect to SharePoint using selected sites permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a client registration for our application with permissions to access a specific SharePoint site that were granted using the sites.selected approach described in the following article. Our application was assigned "Write" role for the site.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

We can retrieve a token for our app registration. However, it does not contain a roles or scp claim, and we get an error informing us of this when we attempt a call to see the lists or drives on the site.

Are we doing something wrong? Does the sites.selected permission not extend to Lists or Drives?

(We are only planning to use the drives call as a once-off operation, so if this is not supported we can probably work around that. Our requirement is to read and write files on the specified sites.)

Here is the request and response where we retrieve the token:
[image]

Here is the request to list the drives:
[image]

Update: I think the problem is that the permissions were granted for the SharePoint API and not the Graph API.

Comment: I think the problem is that the permissions were granted for the SharePoint API and not the Graph API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the **access token** does not have permissions related to **Microsoft Graph** while calling Graph API requests.

When I tried to list drives in site using token having no Graph API permissions, I too got **same error** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant **Microsoft Graph** API permissions of *Application* type in your app registration:

[image]

Now, I generated the **access token** again using client credentials flow via Postman:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, you can decode the access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check whether **`roles`** claim has **valid** permissions or not:

[image]

When I used this token to list drives in SharePoint site, I got the **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I thought this was the case, as per my comment/update, but do not have the access to check. Thank you for verifying it.